# Show $||Ax+b|| < || A\left[x+ \mu D (Ax+b) \right]+b ||$, A is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, positive-definite

Given matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}, D \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times M}$ , vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^M$. 
What is condition of A which will lead to
$$
||Ax+b|| < || A\left[x+ \mu D(Ax+b) \right]+b ||
$$ 
and what is condition of A which will lead to
$$
||Ax+b|| > || A\left[x+ \mu D(Ax+b) \right]+b ||
$$ 
where $\mu$ is a very small positive constant.

Can we prove the inequality when $A$ is positive definite?

This problem is trivial when all entries are numbers:
$$
||ax+b|| < || a\left[x+ (\mu d)(ax+b) \right]+b ||
$$
if $a>0, d>0$.

In the case of matrix and vectors, one can use dot product 
$$
||Ax+b||^2=Ax\cdot Ax + 2Ax\cdot b+ b\cdot b
= x^T(A^T A)x + 2Ax\cdot b+ ||b||^2
$$
to analyze it, but no clue how to proceed further.

Comment: What exactly is your question? This is definitely not true for all vectors. Set $A=[-1,0;0,-1]$, $x=[0,0]$ and $b=[1,1]$ and you have $||[1,1]|| < ||[-\mu,-\mu]+[1,1]||$

Comment: I assume $$ is positive definite.

Comment: You need to make assumptions on $D$ as well. If $A=I_N$ and $D=-I_N/\mu$ and $b=0$ then the right simplifies to $0$. The answer also depends on what you mean by positive definite. The usual definition is that all eigenvalues are positive. Many communities also require that it is symmetric. In either case, it is atypical to call a $M \times N$ matrix positive definite.